# Are github gists SEO friendly?

Tags: javascript, seo

I am kind of fan of Github and it's Gists. Since the gists can be included via a small Javascript snippet and `document.write` commands, I was asking myself if they were SEO friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, no. These things get indexed only if Google makes it special case (like they did with Disqus and Facebook comments).

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the answer. Thought Google among others understood basic Javascript commands. And `document.write` being one of these. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm think, I'm coming back on that vote. Recent searches have shown Google is actually able to execute some pretty complex javascript. Meaning `document.write` is IMO scanned. I will have to confirm it with some online tests.

Comment: @Zenklys this is true that Google executes scripts (even relatively complex ones). They are doing so in order to crawl sites with JS-driven navigation, that don’t provide plain html links to their pages. To my best knowledge, this content doesn’t get indexed, only the links are being followed. Since I don’t work for Google, this may or may not be true; if you do research on this matter that shows otherwise, please tell.

Answer (score 2):

I actually wrote a small app to include a github gist along with its actual content in NOSCRIPT tags. Not sure if Google will pick it up or not though.

http://seo-friendly-gist.heroku.com/ just paste in the gist ID and it will return the code to embed.

Comment: Hey, great idea! After some researh, I finally choose for traditionnel embedded code with google prettify, but still nice example of what Heroku is able todo ;)
One day, I'll give it try! Thanks!